# From MySQL to Mongoose: aggregate document with maximum multiplication of two values in all rows

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

For given table:

```
id | val_a | val_b | mult | category
------------------------------------
 0 | 1     | 2     | 9    | A
 1 | 0     | 3     | 5    | B
 2 | 0.5   | 4     | 6    | C
```

following query in MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category IN ('A','B','C') 
AND IF( val_a > 0, val_a, val_b ) * mult = (SELECT MAX( IF( val_a > 0, val_a, val_b ) * mult ) FROM table WHERE category IN ('A','B','C')) LIMIT 1;
```

will find multiplications of **val_a * mult** for every row (if val_a == 0 : **val_b * mult**)

```
0) 1*9 = 9
1) 3*5 = 15
2) 0.5*4 = 2
```

and then find the maximum of all answers, and finally return row with ID:1

```
1) 15
```

How do I aggregate the same in Mongoose? Even partial answer will help to move forward and to learn.
Tried to start with http://www.querymongo.com/ but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) with [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) to apply filtering condition and then [$multiply](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/index.html) with [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to calculate the value based on your formula. Finally you can add [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) with [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/index.html) to get MAX value. Try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            category: { $in: [ "A", "B", "C" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            value: {
                $multiply: [ { $cond: [ { $ne: [ "$val_a", 0 ] }, "$val_a", "$val_b" ] }, "$mult" ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { value: -1 }
    },
    {
        $limit: 1
    }
])
```

Outputs:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : 15 }
```